# Groovy: Possible to build map of functions?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a list of elements and I want to build a map, that for every element in this list holds a method call. For example:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
map = list.collectEntries{[it: println(it)]}
map[b]

>>b
```

This isn't working because of two problems:

1. `println` gets immediately executed when assigned to the key in the map
2. `map[b]` runs into an error: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:
   No such property: b for class: test`

Is it possible to set up such a map, without the commands getting immediately executed? How can it be done?

NOTE: I know, what I want to achieve sounds a bit strange, but I was given a method, that takes such a map as an argument and then runs the commands, so I do not have another option like for-loops and stuff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to store functions in the map and evaluate them lazily you will have to store these functions as closures for instance. Consider following example:

```
def list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
def map = list.collectEntries { el -> [(el): { println el }] }
map.b()
```

In this case function gets evaluated only when it gets executed and now when it gets assigned to the map key. Also you will have to use explicit name parameter like `el`, because if you rely on `it` it changes the context when accesses the closure.

There are multiple ways you execute function stored in the map. Consider following expressions as an example:

```
map.b()
map.b.call()
map['b']()
map['b'].call()
map.getAt('b').call()
```

If you want to make function execution NPE safe then following expression will be the best choice:

```
map.getAt('b')?.call()
```

In this case calling

```
map.getAt('d')?.call()
```

will not throw any exception.